# Global shared dialog in React

Tags: reactjs

Can't think of a way to implement a simple global modal.
I'm thinking something along the lines:

```
Modal
    show, setShow

    render
        return show && jsx

Component1
    handleShow
        modal.setShow(true)

Component2
    handleShow
        modal.setShow(true)
```

My main issue here is how do I get the reference to the "modal" to call setShow??? I could pass it to props, but how to get an instance to pass it to props?

Now I render modal like this:

```
createRoot(document.getElementById('modals')).render(
    <Modal {...props} />
);
```

While main entrypoints of pages are like this:

```
createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <>
        <Header {...props} />
        <Home {...props} />
        <Footer {...props} />
    </>
);

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <>
        <Header {...props} />
        <Watch {...props} />
        <Footer {...props} />
    </>
);
```

I would like to pass the modal (ref) to the props.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; `Modal` is a component. Put the component in your JSX and set its property normally.

Comment: @DaveNewton added more context, maybe that'll clear things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, came up with this:

```
Modal
   return jsx

Component1
  <App>
    Header
    Home
    Footer

Component2
  <App>
    Header
    Watch
    Footer

App
  show, setShow
  handleClose
    setShow(false)
  
    return (
        <>
            {React.Children.map(props.children, child =>
                React.cloneElement(child, {onClose: handleClose, setShow: setShow}))
            }
            {show &&
                createPortal(
                    <Modal handleClose={handleClose} setShow={setShow}/>,
                    document.body
                )
            }
        </>
    )
```

Basically a container for the children + dialog which shares the state. Satisfied for now, but please do tell if this could be improved.